# Правильное размещение блоков на странице

Tags: html, css, css3

Доброго дня. Сейчас учу html. Хотел бы сделать правильное размещение блоков на странице. [image: Конструкция блоков на странице]
Не подскажите, как правильно задавать блоки, что бы они корректно отображались? Например, что бы отобразить блок 2 (правый) я сделал

```
postion: fixed;
right:0;
```

Но как сделать, что бы третий и четвертый блок меняли свою ширину в соответствии с размещением блока 2? (Например, при уменьшении масштаба в хроме блок 3 и блок 4 растягивались к блоку 2, а не оставались на месте? Благодарю!

Comment: Ну я бы сделал в виде таблицы шириной 100% и с тремя колонками. У первой колонки (где блок 1) и третьей (где блок 2) ширину нужно задать явно, а у средней не задавать. Тогда браузер автоматом подстроит ширину средней ячейки.

Comment: вот простой пример http://jsfiddle.net/7a7hdtz1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #ffffff
}
div.header {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #004e52
}
div.main {
  overflow: hidden
}
div.block1 {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  ;
  background-color: #004e52
}
div.right {
  margin-left: 200px;
  overflow: hidden
}
div.block2 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #004e52
}
div.center {
  margin-right: 200px
}
div.block3 {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #004e52
}
div.block4 {
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #004e52
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="block1">
      block1
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="block2">
        block2
      </div>
      <div class="center">
        <div class="block3">
          block3
        </div>
        <div class="block4">
          block4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Благодарю!!! Вы очень помогли! Разрешите последний вопрос. А возможно ли, что бы на блоке (например block3) был некоторый малый блок, который зависел бы от самого блока? Например, блок по сверху block3 с какими-то данными. Спасибо!